# using pull_to_refresh in view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, pull-to-refresh

i'm so beginner developer in ios world, and it's the first time i try to make a little application. 
my app used UItableview to show the content i've get it from server, i use this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG_AMY_gSDQ
in this tutorial: they used the main view controller and add table view to it, so when i try to add pull to refresh to my view, i can't because i didn't use UITableViewController. 
so is there any way to refresh my content without using UITableViewController ?
and thank you so mush for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You will need to initialize UIRefreshControl manually then addsubview to your tableView

```
var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    myTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

func refresh(sender: AnyObject){
   // this function will be called whenever you pull your list for refresh
}
```

Comment: thanks so mush. i apply your above code, and when i try to pull my view, it's work but the pull_to_refresh sign didn't disappear  and the whole app freezing. why ?

Comment: You must be sure that after refresh operation is complete to call refreshControl.endRefreshing()